# Autocomplete attribute shows no results

Tags: magento, magento2, algolia

I've set up Algolia on my Magento site. I have an attribute successfully set up on the Instant Results search page, but I can't that same attribute to yield results in the Autocomplete dropdown.

My attribute is "Brand" ("le_brand"). Brand names will display in the autocomplete dropdown as I type them

[image]

, but the URL they lead to doesn't include the brand name ([screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhmjV.png)).

[Here are my Magento Algolia plugin settings for this attribute.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geZnm.png)

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Hello Lauren, there was a bug in the extension which caused "undefined" instead of real value. Fix is already merged into master branch, so feel free to update the extension via Composer. Here's merged PR: https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-magento-2/pull/93

Answer (score 0):

For anyone researching this issue, the recent bug fix resolved this. Thanks, Jan! github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-magento-2/pull/93